# Get Element value with minidom with Python

Tags: python, dom, minidom

I am creating a GUI frontend for the Eve Online API in Python.

I have successfully pulled the XML data from their server.

I am trying to grab the value from a node called "name":

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
dom = parse("C:\\eve.xml")
name = dom.getElementsByTagName('name')
print name
```

This seems to find the node, but the output is below:

```
[<DOM Element: name at 0x11e6d28>]
```

How could I get it to print the value of the node?

Comment: It's starting to look like the answer to most "minidom" questions is "use ElementTree".

Comment: Otoh, if you learn minidom instead of ElementTree, you may take a little longer to start, but you will then be able to do exactly the same thing in practically any other programming language you know or eventually learn, and also be able to leverage many other tools. You pays your money and takes your choice.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

It should just be

```
name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: When I do name[0].nodeValue is gives back "None", just to test I passed it name[0].nodeName and it gave me "name" which is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: What about name[0].firstChild.nodeValue ?

Comment: Just beware that you are not relying on implementation details in the xml-generator. There are no guarantees that the first child is *the* text node nor the *only* text node in any cases where there can be more than one child node.

Comment: Why would anyone design a library in which the nodeValue of <name>Smith</name> is anything but "Smith"?! That little nugget cost me 30 minutes of tearing my hair out. I'm bald now. Thanks, minidom.

Comment: It's just because of the way they designed it to work with html, to allow for elements such as this <nodeA>Some Text<nodeinthemiddle>__complex__structure__</nodeinthemiddle>Some more text</nodeA>, in this case do you think nodeA's nodeValue should contain all text including the complex structure, or simply 2 text nodes and the middle node. Not the nicest way to look at it, but I can see why they did it.

Comment: You, sir, are a legend

Comment: Why would anyone design a huge complicated car, when all *I* ever need is to get from home to places within 3 blocks? A bicycle is much better.

Comment: Point staken, but if the car is marketed as a bicycle...and minidom is an xml library, in terms of the libraries it resides in, so denigrating xml functionality for the sake of being able to handle malformed xml seems a bit off. Minidom is quite simply, unsuitable for intuitive xml processing.

Answer (score 63):

Probably something like this if it's the text part you want...

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
dom = parse("C:\\eve.xml")
name = dom.getElementsByTagName('name')

print " ".join(t.nodeValue for t in name[0].childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)
```

The text part of a node is considered a node in itself placed as a child-node of the one you asked for. Thus you will want to go through all its children and find all child nodes that are text nodes. A node can have several text nodes; eg.

```
<name>
  blabla
  <somestuff>asdf</somestuff>
  znylpx
</name>
```

You want both 'blabla' and 'znylpx'; hence the " ".join(). You might want to replace the space with a newline or so, or perhaps by nothing.

Answer (score 12):

you can use something like this.It worked out for me

```
doc = parse('C:\\eve.xml')
my_node_list = doc.getElementsByTagName("name")
my_n_node = my_node_list[0]
my_child = my_n_node.firstChild
my_text = my_child.data 
print my_text
```

Comment: This only gets the text of the first child of the "name" element. So except in the simplest cases it will produce the wrong result.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is pretty old now, but I thought you might have an easier time with [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import datetime

f = ET.XML(data)

for element in f:
    if element.tag == "currentTime":
        # Handle time data was pulled
        currentTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(element.text, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if element.tag == "cachedUntil":
        # Handle time until next allowed update
        cachedUntil = datetime.datetime.strptime(element.text, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if element.tag == "result":
        # Process list of skills
        pass
```

I know that's not super specific, but I just discovered it, and so far it's a lot easier to get my head around than the minidom (since so many nodes are essentially white space).

For instance, you have the tag name and the actual text together, just as you'd probably expect:

```
>>> element[0]
<Element currentTime at 40984d0>
>>> element[0].tag
'currentTime'
>>> element[0].text
'2010-04-12 02:45:45'e
```

Answer (score 8):

The above answer is correct, namely:

```
name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

However for me, like others, my value was further down the tree:

```
name[0].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue
```

To find this I used the following:

```
def scandown( elements, indent ):
    for el in elements:
        print("   " * indent + "nodeName: " + str(el.nodeName) )
        print("   " * indent + "nodeValue: " + str(el.nodeValue) )
        print("   " * indent + "childNodes: " + str(el.childNodes) )
        scandown(el.childNodes, indent + 1)

scandown( doc.getElementsByTagName('text'), 0 )
```

Running this for my simple SVG file created with Inkscape this gave me:

```
nodeName: text
nodeValue: None
childNodes: [<DOM Element: tspan at 0x10392c6d0>]
   nodeName: tspan
   nodeValue: None
   childNodes: [<DOM Text node "'MY STRING'">]
      nodeName: #text
      nodeValue: MY STRING
      childNodes: ()
nodeName: text
nodeValue: None
childNodes: [<DOM Element: tspan at 0x10392c800>]
   nodeName: tspan
   nodeValue: None
   childNodes: [<DOM Text node "'MY WORDS'">]
      nodeName: #text
      nodeValue: MY WORDS
      childNodes: ()
```

I used xml.dom.minidom, the various fields are [explained on this page, MiniDom Python.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly modified answer of Henrik's for multiple nodes (ie. when getElementsByTagName returns more than one instance)

```
images = xml.getElementsByTagName("imageUrl")
for i in images:
    print " ".join(t.nodeValue for t in i.childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)
```

Answer (score 3):

The question has been answered, my contribution consists in clarifying one thing that may confuse beginners:

Some of the suggested and correct answers used `firstChild.data` and others used `firstChild.nodeValue` instead. In case you are wondering what is the different between them, you should remember they do the same thing because `nodeValue` is just an alias for `data`.

The reference to my statement can be found as a comment on the [source code of minidom](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/xml/dom/minidom.py):

> #`nodeValue` is an alias for `data`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case, what worked for me was:

name.firstChild.childNodes[0].data

XML is supposed to be simple and it really is and I don't know why python's minidom did it so complicated... but it's how it's made

Answer (score 2):

It's a tree, and there may be nested elements. Try:

```
def innerText(self, sep=''):
    t = ""
    for curNode in self.childNodes:
        if (curNode.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE):
            t += sep + curNode.nodeValue
        elif (curNode.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE):
            t += sep + curNode.innerText(sep=sep)
    return t
```