# XML Parsing with python minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-3.x, minidom

I am trying to html parse a XML file and getting the contents of a tag to print in a list. Below is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.caltesting.mt.caaspp</groupId>
  <artifactId>mt-web</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.365-20150828.172422-3</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.373-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.365-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.366-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.367-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.368-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.369-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.370-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.372-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>1.0.373-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20150925021611</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

My Python Code to parse this and print the version numbers(1.0.3XX) in the version tag with versions tag.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('/Users/Downloads/metadata.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('version')
for s in itemlist:
    print(s)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may just construct a list of versions via a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
versions = [version[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            for version in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('version')]
```

See also:

- [Get Element value with minidom with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317413/get-element-value-with-minidom-python)

Comment: When I use the single line of code you mentioned here I am getting a Attribute error: 

AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

But I was able to use the version[0].firstChild.nodeValue bit and get the solution for my problem thanks :)